# Mashery with external identity provider like IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, ibm-api-management, mashery

Does Mashery play nicely with a third party OAuth2/OpenID Connect provider? Can it be configured to allow OAuth2 tokens to pass through? If so, how much functionality of Mashery is lost by going with a different identity provider?

I am currently using IdentityServer4 but will soon be using Mashery and I'd like to understand the implications of using both.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if Mashery support oAuth tokens generated by external parties ?

Answer is no. And I don't think they have any plans to implement it soon.